# MySQL, multi column indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have two MySQL queries which I use to help me arrange news on my website. All the fields here indicated are numeric (int or tinyint) and all have an index on them. Can somebody help me build the multi column indexes which will speed up the two queries please?

```
SELECT MAX(content_time) AS content_time 
  FROM cm_data 
 WHERE content_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
   AND page = '1' 
   AND (content_type = '1' OR content_type = '5')

SELECT content_id 
  FROM cm_data
 WHERE (content_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
       OR (hp_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND content_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
          )
       )
   AND page = '1' 
   AND (content_type = '1' OR content_type = '5')
 ORDER BY hp_time DESC
     , content_time DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

And here is the DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cm_data` (
  `content_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hp_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `content_type` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`content_id`),
  KEY `content_time` (`content_time`),
  KEY `content_type` (`content_type`),
  KEY `page` (`page`),
);
```

Comment: The `WHERE` clause on your second statement has a duplicate criteria... saying `content_time < UT() OR ( hp_time >= UT() AND content_time <UT() )` is the exact same as saying `content_time < UT()`.  If the optimizer didn't get rid of that, taking it out will certainly speed up the query.

Comment: Another thing to note (as I can't recall if the mysql query optimizer will take care of this or not...):  try putting the constraints `page = 1` and `(content_type = '1' OR content_type = '5')` before the `content_time < UT()` constraint, to see if that speeds things up.

Comment: thanks @sybkar, i removed the first or and that worked well!

Comment: @sybkar can you give me some insights as to why i should change the order in the where clauses? i would love to understand this better.

Comment: generally, since MySQL documentation doesn't say that it will re-order the constraint evaluation, I wouldn't assume that it does (or doesn't) re-order them.  When the constraint is costly (comparing TIMESTAMPs, STRINGs, etc), it would be better to place it after less costly (INT) comparisons to reduce the number of times it is performed.  This may be the case here, since UNIX_TIMESTAMP() returns an UNSIGNED INT, and the columns are stored as INTs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes aren't always the answer (especially where many `INSERT` statements are to be expected).  That being said, there are a couple of things you can do to optimize these queries:

1)  Make sure your constraints are properly formed.  In the second query, you have essentially `Case1 OR ( Case2 AND Case1 )`, which can be simplified to just `Case1` (boolean algebra).  Making sure these are as reduced as possible *before* the query optimizer looks at it can not only reduce the effort required by the optimizer, but also catch cases that it can't resolve.

2)  Check the order of your constraints.  Since it doesn't state anywhere in the documentation that the query optimizer will check the constraints in any specific order for non-unique keys, a little knowledge of optimization can be used to potentially speed up queries.  Generally speaking, evaluation of non-integer constraints will be costly (STRINGs, etc).  In your case, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() returns an UNSIGNED INT, whereas the field is specified as an INTEGER.  This will result in a cast operation for each row, which will be costly.  So, if you can reduce the number of times the comparisons must be done (by filtering out rows with simpler constraints first), fewer operations must be performed, leading to a shorter execution time.

2a) MySQL doesn't support indexes on functions, so you could either change the datatype of the field to UNSIGNED INT (preferred if available), or create an additional column which gets updated with a trigger which contains the UNSIGNED INT equivalent of the field, and index it instead.  The latter isn't ideal, but could offer some performance increase at the expense of increased table size.